# Overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, css-position, bootstrap-5

I want my navbar to be sticky on the top all the time even when i scroll but when i scroll, the content of my cards dont cut, so it´s content goes on top of my navbar and i dont understand what i am missing? Any thougts? Im using bootstrap 5.

```css
nav {
  background-color: black;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.nav {
  color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
  margin: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="../../index.html" class="nav">Home</a>
  <a href="./products.html" class="nav">Products</a>
  <a href="./about.html" class="nav">About us</a>
  <a href="./contact.html" class="nav">Contact</a>
</nav>

<main class="container">
  <div class="row gy-3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/99" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text
           to build on the card title and make up the 
            bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

I also tried and put the img in my card inside a div and use overflow:hidden;...it didnt work.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also fix your markup. You're missing several closing tags.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0):

If the navbar should be at the top of your window *all the time* without moving, use `position: fixed` instead of `sticky`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i tried that but the same problem occured...?

Answer (score -1):

Put some z-index to your nav. like `z-index: 10;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thank you for the reply. And yes i thougt of that, but it must be another way right? Like a more "correct" way lets say?

Comment: Why it's not the "correct" way for you? z-index is nothing special and no bad stuff  this is the right way, when you want to position elements above others

Comment: Okey thank you, im just asking i dont know i´m a newbie  so i appreciate any inputs:D it just felt like a quickfix move, but surely it did work so thank you! But im thinking it would be enough if i have overflow:hidden; in my nav or in my .container or something like that?